# After much struggle

Tags: traducción, vocabulario, gramática

The sentence I am trying to translate is:

> The young man found work after much (a lot of) struggle.

Is one of these the most appropriate way (somehow it doesn’t seem so to me, that’s why I ask)?

- El joven encontró trabajo después de muchas pruebas.
- El joven encontró trabajo después de mucha lucha.

Also if I were to replace the “*…after much struggle*” in the same sentence with “*…after a long time*”, would it translate as “**…después de mucho tiempo**”?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*El joven encontró trabajo después de muchas pruebas.*

Es correcta pero parecería que has tenido que pasar pruebas (u exámenes) ya sean psicológicos, médicas, de aptitud, de actitud... o como en muchas entrevistas de trabajo pruebas de selección.

Para traducir *struggle* en el sentido de lucha ante una adversidad me decantaría por tu segunda opción

**El joven encontró trabajo después de mucha lucha.**

O por esfuerzo

**El joven encontró trabajo después de mucho esfuerzo.**

*After a long time / después de mucho tiempo* es correcta.

Comment: At one point, you say, “…ante una adversidad”. Is this different from saying, “…contra una adversidad.”? Sorry for this detour but I really got curious about the most appropriate way of translating “against” in Spanish.

Comment: @Amit Schandillia Both prepositions are ok, you can use "contra una adversidad".

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I would still love to find out if there’s any preference for one over the other when it comes to colloquial speech. Any regional variance?

Comment: Le costó mucho al joven encontrar trabajo